# How to reference top-level container throughout application without making it a singleton?

Tags: java, swing, singleton, containers

How can I reference a top-level container (e.g. a `JFrame`) throughout an application without making it a singleton? The reason I ask is that I'm trying to avoid the singleton antipattern.

Anyway, I find that when I need another top-level container (e.g. a `JDialog`) to display a simple message to the user, I want this dialog to be placed directly over the aforementioned `JFrame` using `setLocationRelativeTo(frame)`. But the only way I can do so (at the moment), is to make a single instance of the `JFrame` and access it using a static `getInstance` method.

So, is there a way to reference a top-level container without having to resort to the singleton pattern? Please let me know if anyone needs more information!

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with a Singleton if that is the behavior you want. The issue arises when you implement a Singleton only to have a global variable and start using them everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a reference to any Swing component held in the top level window, such as can be obtained from an Event object's (such as an ActionEvent) `getSource()` method, you can use this to get the top level window via a [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) method:

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(anyComponent);
```

This class also has other useful and similar methods such as `windowForComponent(Component c)` `getDeepestComponentAt(...)` and `getRoot(Component c)`

Otherwise you can always pass references via constructor or setter parameters.

Comment: (Just a sanity check) If there is a `JButton` on a `JPanel` that sits on a `JFrame`, if I invoke this method on the `JButton`, will it return the `JFrame`? I think the answer would be **yes**, since `JPanel` isn't a `Window`, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask an expert! :D

Comment: @mre: Yes, it will return the top-level Window which in your case would be the JFrame.

Comment: See also [`JComponent.getTopLevelAncestor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor%28%29).  +1 for the pointer to `gWA()` - my learn item of the day.  :)

Comment: @mKorbel: and thanks for yours. I've already +1 you a while ago.

Answer (score 3):

1) Current JVM instance can returns array of `Top-level Containers`, including disposed

```
Window[] allWindows = Window.getWindows();
```

by default all of `Top-level Containers` are accesible and ready for re_use

2) `JFrame` can returns all childs, including disposed, notice if is there 2.nd or more JFrames then required usage `getWindows()`

```
Window[] allWindows = Window.getOwnedWindows();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your dialogs (JDialog) with the parent specified, this way you can store the reference to the parent object, have a look into JDialog constructor:

```
public JDialog(Frame owner)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame%29